# Core data returns extra null values while fetching data?

Tags: ios, core-data

While fetching data, it returns records with null values (number of records multiply by method call count)

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self getContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category_List" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[request setEntity:entity];

NSError *error1 = nil;

NSArray *results1 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error1];

NSLog(@"Fetch Request Data Count = %lu", (unsigned long)[results1 count]);
```

Comment: You should try to actually write a question inside the body of your question. What would you expect to get returned and what is actually getting returned - just code and a title are not sufficient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just call the reset method of the context and my problem is solved.

```
[context reset];
```